# elasticity of labor supply

Tags: elasticity, search-and-matching

Labor supply is

$ L(s,H) = \frac{f(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)} H $

Now the elasticity wrt to tightness $\theta$ is supposed to be

$\epsilon_L= \epsilon_f - \frac{f(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)} \epsilon_f$

where $\epsilon_f$ is the elasticity of $f$ wrt to tightness. Why? If I take substitute in $ L(s,H)$ and take the derivative with the quotient rule I end up nowhere..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that:
$$
L(s,H) = \frac{f(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)}H.
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\theta$:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = \frac{f'(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)}H - \frac{f(\theta)}{(s + f(\theta))^2} f'(\theta) H
$$

Dividing by $L$ and mulitplying by $\theta$ gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
\epsilon_L &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}\frac{\theta}{L} = \frac{f'(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)} H \frac{\theta (s + f(\theta)}{f(\theta)H} - \frac{f(\theta)}{(s + f(\theta))^2} f'(\theta) H \frac{\theta (s + f(\theta))}{f(\theta)H},\\
&= \epsilon_f - \frac{f(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)} f'(\theta)\frac{\theta}{f(\theta)},\\
&= \epsilon_f - \frac{f(\theta)}{s + f(\theta)} \epsilon_f
\end{align*}
$$